# Prove that sequence is in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{K}$ a sequence such that $\forall a\in l^1$ the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{i=1} a_i c_i$$ exists.

Show that $(c_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}$

---

I'm not really sure how to handle this question. My naive approach seems too simple. Since I know, that $(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^1$ it follows that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} |a_n|<\infty \Rightarrow \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n<\infty$. Then, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=0$

Let's assume w.l.o.g. that $a_i = 1/i^2$  (then $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^1$) and $c_i=i^2$ (and therefore not in $l^{\infty}$ because the sequence isn't bounded).

Then,

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{i=1} a_i c_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum^n_{i=1} 1 \rightarrow \infty $$

which is a contradiction that the limit should exist.

I'd like to have some feedback on my proof and maybe some tips how to solve it correctly (if I did it wrong)

Comment: You can pick an $a_I$ WLOG because it is supposed to work for all $a_i$.  But you can't pick a specific $c_i$ WLOG and then try to say something holds for all $c_i$.

Comment: The thing you want to assume for sake of contradiction is that $c_i$ is unbounded in at least one direction, and show that that is going to force at least one $a_i$ that is in $l_1$ to fail to converge as a product

Comment: You have only shown that one specific sequence, namely $(i^2),$ fails to have the given property. You need to show that if $(c_i)$ is unbounded, then there exists $(a_i)\in l^1$ such that $\sum a_ic_i$ diverges.

Comment: @Alan Okay, I get that. Not sure if I'm overthinking the problem, but what if I let $(c_i)$ be unbounded $\rightarrow \infty$. And then I define $c^*_i:=\max{c_{i-1}, c_i}$, which essentially means that $(c^*_i)$ is monotone unbounded. Then define $a_i:=1/(c_i^*)$. By root test, we have that $\lim \sup \sqrt[i]{a_i}  \rightarrow 0<1$, so $\sum |a_i|$ is convergent and $(a_i) \in l^1$. But also, $\sum c_i a_i \rightarrow \infty$. since it's arithmetic for infinite many elements.

Comment: @Quotenbanane I don't think it would work, for example, if $c_i=\log i$, or even $c_i=i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|c_i|\to\infty$ so one can construct a subsequence $k_1<k_2<...$ with $|c_{k_n}|>n^2$

Define $a_i=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}c_{k_n}}{n^2}$ if $i=k_n$ for some $n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then $\sum |a_i|=\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$, but $\sum a_i c_i>\sum\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n^2=\infty$